# Draggable child doesn't drop at dragtarget but goes back to its position

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put / drop `draggable` child onto the corresponding `dragtarget`, but it doesn't get dropped and comes back to its original position.

[image]

As you can see from picture, I want to put the `red container` on top of `green container` that has matching letter, but as soon as I release the pointer, the `red container` goes back and `green container` shows `?` again. Below is the `Draggable` and `DragTarget` code snippet:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: inputList.map((i) {
              print(i);
              return Draggable<String>(
                data: i,
                feedback: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Text(i.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Text(i.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: outputList.map((o) {
                  return DragTarget<String>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          List<String> candidateData,
                          List<dynamic> rejectedData) {
                        if (candidateData.isEmpty) {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Text('?',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center));
                        } else {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Text(o.toUpperCase(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center));
                        }
                      },
                      onWillAccept: (data) => data == o,
                      onAccept: (data) {
                        setState(() {
                         // what to set here
                        });
                      },
                      onLeave: (data) {});
                }).toList(),
              )),
```

Not sure what am I missing in the code above. Basically I want to have all `?` containers to be replaced with corresponding letters in `blue container` using drag and drop.

Anybody know the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget/builder.html):

> The builder can build different widgets depending on what is being dragged into this drag target.

You need to check if candidateData (acceptedData) is not empty in the builder callBack, in which case return a widget containing the matched latter.

```
builder: (...) =>
  candidateData.isNotEmpty
    //The returning widget for the matched letter.
    ? Container()
    //The returning widget for the un-matched letter or without dragging anything.
    : Container(),
```

The builder callBack is called everytime something is dragged over this DragTarget widget. And the candidateData (acceptedData) will not be empty if onWillAccept callBack returned true and vice versa. Also the same thing applies to rejectedData, but in the opposite way.

So the order of `DragTarget` callBacks execution is:

1. builder : Called initially without dragging anything over.
2. onWillAccept :Called if you drag something over (holding the touch).
3. builder : Called immediately after onWillAccept, but its last two parameters are based on onWillAccept result (still holding the touch).
4. onAccept or onLeave: One of them will be called depending on if you drop (releasing the touch) the `Draggable` over this `DragTarget` or you throw it away.
5. builder: It will be called for the last time, but at the moment its last two parameters are empty.

Comment: @Darshan My friend, you can define an outsider variable and set & get its content between the builder, onWillAccept, onAccept and onLeave. It's up to your configuration. But, I updated my answer to reflect the order of executing all the callBacks of `DragTarget`.

Comment: Thanks. Your detailed explanation helped me understand the builder cycle and solved the issue.